# Classification of singularities of a complex function and the method of Darboux

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics

I am interested in the following complex function
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{-2+c+2z-cz+c\sqrt{1-2z+(5-4c)z^2}}
$$
for $c$ an integer strictly greater than $2$. I will need to apply the method of Darboux to estimate the asymptotic growth of coefficients $b_n$ with $n$ in the Maclaurin expansion
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^n\ .\qquad (\star)
$$
To this end, I need to find the radius of convergence of $(\star)$, i.e. possibly the closest singularity to the origin (and its type).

Trusting Mathematica, it seems that the denominator vanishes at the points $z^\star_\pm=\frac{1}{1\pm c}$, and I believe there are two branch points at $z_b=\frac{\pm2 \sqrt{c-1}-1}{4 c-5}$, so I would be tempted to conclude that the closest singularity to the origin is $z^\star_+=\frac{1}{1+c}$, but I am unconvinced and cannot classify it.

So, my question is: what is the closest singularity to the origin of the function above, and its type?

Many thanks for any help and suggestions you may have!